# Wordpress Graphql - Can I filter by acf column?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm trying to filter my query result of spost (my cpt), but I can not find the option to filter by acf columns. Is there any way for WPGraphQL to filter result by acf?

[image: My graphiql interface for "spost" (a custom post type)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to filter connection by ACF field, due to how costly this feature would be on the database. The only alternative at the moment is adding there parameter to connection using WPGraphQL connection API.

https://docs.wpgraphql.com/extending/connections/